# AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory removed from Jersey 2.26

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I upgrade Jersey in my project to 2.26 version.

My code is:

```
    import org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory;

    public class ClassA extends AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<ClassB> {

            @Override
            public ClassB provide() {
                    .....
            }

    }
```

AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory class was removed, and I didn't found how to fix this.

Comment: This is very easy to find on GitHub: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3630 Essentially: Do not use classes in the `internal.*` packages.

Comment: I saw this page, but I don't know which class I have to use.
What can I use instead of `AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory`?

Comment: @JuanPommerenck Any update regarding this issue?, I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/jersey/jersey/commit/1f4614787c4cfddb5d9177c6c2a663b96ab673cc#diff-bcd9d3f0cfac8ea5e8e9a6b00119237b 
commit we can see we should use below code instead.

```
private static final class BeanParamValueProvider implements Function<ContainerRequest, Object> {
```

Comment: Can anyone apply this answer to the code provided in the question. This doesn't seem to address the AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory that the question mentions...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we can use custom HK2 bindings, that are configured as part of Jersey application. Add jersey-hk2 dependency dependency in the classpath `org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2`

**Define the Factory class to generate the instance based on the resource scopes**

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
@Provider
public class ClassA implements Factory<ClassB> {
    @Override
    public ClassB provide() {
        // construct ClassB instance based on your requirement 
        //here I am simply returning the object
        return new ClassB();
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose(ClassB instance) {/**Noop**/}
}
```

**Registering the custom factory class**

For instance, I have to inject ClassB instance for every request then I can register the above factory with the scope of `RequestScoped`, in such case, for every request `ClassA#provide` will be called to create the value of ClassB instance that can be retrieved as `@Context ClassB classB`

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
@Provider
class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(ClassA.class)
                        .to(ClassB.class)
                        .in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The following scopes are currently supported by Jersey
[image]